# MDX Make a set of all cousins

Tags: set, mdx, aggregation, members

Can anyone help me to solve the followinig MDX related problem ?

I'd need to aggregate a value over a specific set of members.

This set consists of the currentmember and all his cousins (members at the same relative position from their parents as my currentmember) from the "uncles" that are preceeding his parent.

Example :

AAA   BBB   CCC   DDD   EEE

123   123   123   123   123

If my current member is C3, my result set would be C3 + B3 + A3

Thanks in advance to the champ' that will find the solution to this !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Cousin function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145481).